# Bot Framework Getting 502 Bad Gateway Errors in Production Environment after the Bot is not Requested for around 10 Minutes (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, firebase, botframework

When I use Microsoft Bot Framework for developing a conversational bot using multiple waterfall dialogs, I always receive **502 Bad Gateway** errors in the **Production Environment** when the bot is not requested for around **10 Minutes**.

However, in the local environment, the error will not happen when the application is tested using Bot Emulator.

I have been looking for solutions regarding this issue, and it seems that the error is caused by the bot not being able to send back the response within **15 Seconds**.

Here are the things that I have tried in order to get around with the issue:

- Enabled "Always on" options for Azure Cloud Application (cannot solve the issue)

[Azure "Alway On" Option Enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NuNq.png)

- Changed the in-memory storage of state into custom storage using Cosmos DB (cannot solve the issue)

[Cosmos DB for State Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yggSt.png)

- Sending Proactive Messages for certain long-running processes. However, when the 502 error starts to happen, even fetching one document from Firebase Firestore can be the "long-running process" which results in the error. Since my application requires checking Firebase document status constantly to see whether certain conversation stage is open and decide which **Dialog** should be applied, it is unlikely to identify long-running processes in this context.

[Firebase Request in the Initial Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5wLF.png)

Based on my observation, when the 502 gateway error occurs, the bot will be stuck in the initial stage rather than running slowly (i.e. the bot will be stuck in the initial Firebase request), and it does not seem to be the problem of long-running processes.

Also, when the error occurs, the error message throwing by the bot framework is as follows, and I cannot find any related solutions for the error `activity.code with value "14" must be of type string`.

> [onTurnError]: Error: No connection established
>   BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(): 500 ERROR - Error: activity.code with value "14" must be of type string. (node:5132) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: activity.code with value "14" must be of type string. At BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity (D\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\botFrameworkAdapter.js:511:19) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7). (node:5132) Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 9)

Considering this situation, what is the proper workaround of the issue?

- I am trying to write a cloud function to actively sending requests to the bot at a 5 minutes interval to keep it alive, but I am not sure whether it will be working and it does not seem to be the proper solution.
- If I need to send proactive messages for every received message (since it is not possible to identify long-running processes), how can I push the waterfall dialog forward & prompt users for certain inputs with proactive messages? Since the Proactive Message Sample *https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript* does not provide an implementation to continue the waterfall dialog & prompt user for certain inputs (e.g. AttachmentPrompt, NumberPrompt, etc.).

Comment: I don't understand. It seems like you've figure out where it's going wrong (the firebase call). Is the firebase call just not returning? If your dialog is hanging until that call returns, and it doesn't come back in 15 seconds, yeah, it's gonna time out.

Comment: @JJ_Wailes It is not a problem with Firebase. What I mean is that fetching data from Firebase (which basically should take no time) will appear to be long-running processes when the bot does not appear to be "active" after around 10 minutes. The issue is that the bot seems not being capable of sending the fetching requests.

Comment: Can you post this error (your on turn error) on this repo? https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js

Comment: @JJ_Wailes Sure, I have posted this issue on GitHub.